# How to resolve trust anchor issue in android?

Tags: android, retrofit2

I am using trying to call .net api from android application using retrofit2

The apis are working fine when calling from postman.But, from Android side, it is throwing error like this->

```
java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found
```

What should I do to resolve this issue?

My target SDK is 32 and minimum SDK is 24.